# mysql server admin error from workbench

Tags: server, mysql, mysql-workbench

I installed MySQL Workbench and would like to create a new server instance to admin the server, but I got following error message when I create a instance for local server.

Operation failed: File /etc/my.cnf doesn't exist

it looks like I need create a configuration file for new instance.
Can you please help me how to fix the issue?
Your help and information is great appreciated,

Regards,

Inung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are a number of parameters that can be adjusted within MySQL's configuration file that will allow you to improve the performance of the server over time. For initial set-up you may find [Percona's my.cnf](https://tools.percona.com/) generating tool useful. This tool will help generate a my.cnf file that will be much more optimised for your specific server capabilities and your requirements.
>
> Do not replace your existing my.cnf file with Percona's one if you have already loaded data into the database. Some of the changes that will be in the file will be incompatible as they alter how data is stored on the hard disk and you'll be unable to start MySQL.

[**Source**](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html)